# What difference is there between calling tkinter.mainloop() and window.mainloop()?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit

If I want to create an empty window (i.e. one with no widgets) I can do so by running a program with this code:

```
import tkinter
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.mainloop()
```

I can make (apparently) the same thing with the code:

```
import tkinter
window = tkinter.Tk()
tkinter.mainloop()
```

What, if anything, is the overall difference between the two pieces of code? In addition, could there be a situation in which the two lines

```
tkinter.mainloop()
```

and

```
window.mainloop()
```

result in a visibly different output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What difference is there between calling tkinter.mainloop() and window.mainloop()?

There is no difference.

Comment: So with testing I can see that `tkinter.mainloop` and `app_name.mainloop()`do the same thing so why do we use the convention `app_name.mainloop()`? All I can find in the documentation is the example but no explanation of why we use this convention instead of just calling `tkinter.mainloop()` It does seam like a trivial issue to me but I am curious all the same.

Comment: @SierraMountainTech: why? I don't know. In my opinion it makes the code easier to read and understand, but I don't speak for anyone else.

Comment: Ok so it is a preference thing. I was just wondering if there was any functional reason to do it this way.

Comment: I'd guess that the method on a window is a convenience; the underlying library has the main-loop processing as a (thread-)global concept, so `tkinter.mainloop` would be the natural name from Python.